# sort arraylist with objects that have more than one field

Tags: sorting, object, collections, arraylist

I've asked it before, but I have an `ArrayList<Score> scores;` a Score class contains `myPlayerScore(int)` and `myPlayerName(Name)`. I want to take this `ArrayList` and order all the Score objects from lowest to highest based on the `myPlayerScore field (int)`. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Java? Search for Comparable inteerface

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply necessary sorting at data source level (Either in stored procedure that returns that data or in the DataTable in c# code)